# Customizing 'Register New Account' page of JBoss Portal

Tags: java, jboss, portal, jboss-portal

I am new to Portlets and Jboss.

**There is a requirement to add a new custom field in the register form that is displayed.** We'll have to add a new field 'UserType' to capture the type of the user. The UserType has to be eventually stored in the database.

Can you give me pointers on how I could accomplish this ? What should I learn to accomplish this task ?

Is modifying the source code of Jboss Portlet necessary for this requirement ?

[image]

Comment: What version you are using?

Comment: Have you tried shadowing the registration form? Something like: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/GTNPORTAL35/Custom+Sign+in+Page . As you seem to be using JBoss Portal, you might get a faster answer by contacting Red Hat's support directly.